# jquery ajax always get error

Tags: jquery

I just found out this problem, it was because of `<a herf=javascript:void(0)>`!

I have the below jQuery code. It is used to get constants and display target video.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                ..
                success:function(html){
                    $("#searchResultsVideoList").html(html);
                }
            });
            $("[id^='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/']").live("click",
                function(){
                    presentVideo($(this).attr("id"));
                }
            );
            function presentVideo(videoId) {
                var params = 'operation=show_video&videoId=' + videoId;
                var filePath = 'show.php';
                $.ajax({
                    url:"cntl.php",
                    dataType:"html",
                    cache:false,
                    success:function(html){
                        $("#searchResultsVideoColumn").html(html);
                    },
                    error:function(XMLResponse){
                        alert(XMLResponse.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

The problem is that the second $.ajax is basically copy from the first $.ajax,
but the second $.ajax always gets an error - *and* it alert nothing! If I replace the first $.ajax by the second $.ajax, it also works!

Comment: 1) Check the browser console to see any errors which the request is causing 2) don't store your URL in the `id` attribute. Use `data-*` or `href`.

Comment: How is the script failing?  Can you comment on differences in request/response headers for both requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in the second $.ajax call you are not sending the params

```
           var params = 'operation=show_video&videoId=' + videoId;
            var filePath = 'show.php';
            $.ajax({
                url:"cntl.php",
                data: params,
                dataType:"html",
                cache:false,
                success:function(html){
                    $("#searchResultsVideoColumn").html(html);
                },
                error:function(XMLResponse){
                    alert(XMLResponse.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: yes, this code is for testing, the cntl.php gets nothing from fount page. cntl.php just echo something.

Comment: Now success, error, complete are deprecated. Use done(), fail(), always() instead.

Answer (score 0):

you have used two different control in each of your ajax call, In first it is **searchResultsVideoList** and in second it is **searchResultsVideoColumn**. Check are these correct?

Comment: yes, it's correct. those $.ajax work if is outside the click action.->$("[id^='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/']").live("click",

Answer (score 0):

use firebug in firefox to check the ajax call. simply go to console and click on the ajax call. you can see the call and the response. otherwise you could extend your error callback:

```
error : function(XMLHttpRequest, statusText, errorThrown) {
        $('#error').text("");
        $('#error').append(statusText);
        $('#error').append(" - ");
        $('#error').append(XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
        $('#error').append(" - ");
        $('#error').append(errorThrown);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

did you copy that ajax call from somewhere? which editor do you use? sometimes editors mix up charsets if you copied it from somewhere. in that case try to convert the charset to utf8 or whichever you use.

use firefox
install firebug
press f12
hit refresh

console:
there has to be sth. like : "POST http://yourlocalhost:port/yourajax"
click on that
and there has to be "header post response html/json/(whatever you return)"
what does it say?